# MySQL - Optimal Collation?

Tags: mysql, encoding, collation

We are starting to get our product more internationalized, and we are starting to encounter issues with foreign characters, mostly from Spanish and European (Greek, etc), and are wondering what is the best collation to use for tables that will need to contain these characters? Until now, we always let PHPMyAdmin choose the collation it wants, but we feel we need a bit more control.

Thanks.

Comment: Unicode unicode unicode... It's the easiest to deal with and the easiest to translate into and out of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`utf8_general_ci` is the safe way to go, especially since you're supporting several languages with special characters.

`utf8_general_ci` considers all accented characters to be equivalent its accent-less counter part.  e é è ë are all the same to `utf8_general_ci` so it provides a small performance increase. On the other hand, it isn't as accurate as `utf8_unicode_ci` for sorting and might have some trouble with characters like ß or other ligatures.

So basically if you need some precise sorting use `utf8_unicode_ci`, otherwise go for `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: I figured, but under the UTF8 listing, there are a ton of options. Is there a particular one I want? UTF8_bin?

Comment: What does the _general_ci suffix mean?

Comment: nevermind, found this: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10344217.html

Comment: Yeah sorry I hit submit a bit too quick, edited with more details.

Comment: So, for general, will it physically strip the accent characters out? Or only use the base character when doing searches and comparisons? That is, how does it compare to utf8_unicode?

Comment: No, the accent is there in the record, but it will consider `éxämplè` and `example` to be the same for sorting and comparisons. `utf8_unicode` will consider both strings different.

Comment: Just talked with the boss, utf8_general_ci is the one we'll use, thanks a LOT!